# swiftmailer - failures by reference?

Tags: swiftmailer

I am using swiftmailer

Currently to record failures I use

`if(!$mailer->send()) //failed`

but,

I am aware that you can do

> Pass a by-reference variable name to the send() or batchSend() methods of the Mailer class.
>   If the Transport rejects any of the recipients, the culprit addresses will be added to the >array provided by-reference.

My question is,

Does `if(!$mailer->send())` catch bounces?
i send my emails one at a time as they all have modified contents, so I am never sending to more that one address at a time.

are there any benefits to me specifically by using the second method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no benefit to you if sending a customised message per recipient. `send()` does not catch bounces. SMTP can accept messages initially and later bounce them to the address specified in your return path header. You have to be able to read the bounce account in script or have a mail filter redirect the bounce email to a script to handle bounces automatically.